# Xamarin.iOS ReactiveUI ReactiveTableViewCell Not Binding

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, reactiveui

I am working on a Xamarin.iOS app and I am new to ReactiveUI.

I'm trying to bind some properties in a custom table cell that implements `ReactiveTableViewCell` and `IViewFor<>`.

The examples I have seen just show binding to the `TextLabel.Text`, which works fine for me, but when trying to bind to other properties on the table cell that was generated in the UI designer, nothing binds/displays.

The setup is very similar to [ReactiveTableViewSource-Sample](https://github.com/reicheltp/ReactiveTableViewSource-Sample) however I am trying to bind to a label I placed using the designer rather than the default `TextLabel.Text`.

Here is my call to bind the table to the custom tablecell.

```
ViewModel.WhenAnyValue(vm => vm.SearchResults)
    .BindTo<AgentSearchResult, AgentSearchResultsTableCell>
    (agentsTableView, 64, cell => cell.Initialize());
```

Here is my Initialize method in the custom tablecell.

```
public void Initialize()
{
    this.WhenAnyValue(v => v.ViewModel.Name).BindTo
        (this, v => v.lblName.Text); // Doesn't Work
    this.WhenAnyValue(v => v.ViewModel.Name).BindTo
        (this, v => v.TextLabel.Text); // Works
    this.WhenAnyValue(v => v.ViewModel.Agency).BindTo
        (this, v => v.lblCompany.Text);
    this.WhenAnyValue(v => v.ViewModel.Phone).BindTo
        (this, v => v.lblPhone.Text);
    this.WhenAnyValue(v => v.ViewModel.Email).BindTo
        (this, v => v.lblEmail.Text);

}
```

- Default TextLabel.Text binds, but additional properties won't bind/display on table view.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was able to get this working.  It was a rather simple fix but I just didn't see any examples/documentation for it.

The issue was that any items added with the designer were null.

Here is how I fixed it with Storyboards using the designer:

1. Ensure you set an Identifier for the prototype cell that you mocked up.
   [Set TableViewCell Identifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YY1D6.png)
2. Update the binding in your ViewController for the TableView to include the CellKey.

   ```
   ViewModel.WhenAnyValue(vm => vm.SearchResults).BindTo<AgentSearchResult, AgentSearchResultsTableCell>(agentsTableView, new NSString("AgentSearchResultsCell"), 64, cell => cell.Initialize());
   ```

After making these changes the databinding worked perfectly.